# LINQ to SQL DataContext Issue

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

I have finally gotten to the point that I am ready to put the new website that I have been working on for a few weeks live and have bumped into the following error:

```
 CS0246: The type or namespace name 'clientconnectDataContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

my connection string

```
 clientconnectDataContext db = new clientconnectDataContext();
```

this is happens whenever I try and load a page that is running a Linq to SQL query. I have the dbml file on the server and its named correctly, everything is also working on the localhost only when I put it live does it throw the error. The only thing I could think of is that I am hosting this in a folder off of the main website and that the App_folder needs to be just off the root of the website (I have tried it in both places to no avail) I know that not putting the website in the root of the host has caused other issues that I have dealt with.

I know that this is a very vague question and I tried to include as much info as I could, if you need any other information I will respond with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is clientconnectDataContext in a separate assembly?

Comment: Is this a website or web app?

Comment: its not in a separate assembly and its a website

Answer (score 0):

If its a website then make sure you have uploaded all three files which make up the *.dbml file, without all the files IIS won't know how to compile the code:

```
YourDataContext.dbml
YourDataContext.dbml.layout
YourDataContext.dbml.designer.cs
```

Comment: But in another website they added Datacontext at the end of the dbml file and I am getting an error when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `clientconnectDataContext()` with the database connection string

```
clientconnectDataContext db = new clientconnectDataContext("put your connection string to your database here ");
```